# How to use graph.getVertices() get specific vertices, Java , Oriendtdb

Tags: orientdb

How to use `graph.getVertices()` get specific vertices.

- My Class name is `Station` has Extended V(Vertex) .
- category' (datatype is LINK)is property of `Station`
- Category's can be '#12:13' or '#12:14' or '#12:15'

I want to use `graph.getVertices()` `JAVA` to get specific `category`.

Something like :

```
graph.getVertices("Station category = '#12:13'");

graph.getVertices("Excluded Station Category = '#12:13'");
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I used this simple structure to try your case (`category` is of type `LINK`):

**CLASSES**:

[image]

and I retrieved the results you're looking for with this code:

**JAVA CODE**:

```
package yourPackage;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OServerAdmin;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;

public class YourClass{
    private static String remote = "remote:localhost/";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String DBname = "yourDBname";
        String currentPath = remote + DBname;
        OServerAdmin serverAdmin;
        try {
            serverAdmin = new OServerAdmin(currentPath).connect("root", "root");
            if (serverAdmin.existsDatabase()) {
                OrientGraph g = new OrientGraph(currentPath);
                String yourRid = "#13:0";
                Iterable<Vertex> targets = g.getVerticesOfClass("Station");
                System.out.println("Category @rid = " + yourRid);
                System.out.println();
                for (Vertex target : targets) {
                    Vertex category = target.getProperty("category");
                    if (category.getId().toString().equals(yourRid)) {
                        System.out.println("Matched Station: " + target.getProperty("name") + "   Category: "
                            + category.getProperty("name") + " (" + category.getId() + ")");
                        System.out.println();
                } else {
                        System.out.println("Excluded Station: " + target.getProperty("name") + "   Category: "
                            + category.getProperty("name") + " (" + category.getId() + ")");
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Database " + DBname + " not found");
            }
            serverAdmin.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Category @rid = #13:0

Matched Station: First   Category: category 1 (#13:0)

Excluded Station: Second   Category: category 2 (#13:1)
Excluded Station: Third   Category: category 3 (#13:2)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Tkaewkunha, did you have a chance to try the query ?

Comment: Hi @Tkaewkunha, did you have a chance to try my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

to get all vertices of Station class, try:
`g.V('_class','Station')`

or to filter by a category field
`g.V('_class','Station').has('category','catvalue 123')`

or if you have multiple to match:
`g.V('_class', 'Station').has('category', T.in,['12:13','12:14'])`

or for specific Id

`g.v('12:13')`

to find if an edge exists between 2 vertices, you can use:
`g.v(stationVtxId).outE('edge_label').sideEffect{x=it}.inV.filter{it == g.v(catVtxId)}.back(2)`

Answer (score 0):

I used an index on the property category of the class Station

```
create class Station extends V
create class Category extends V

create property Station.name STRING
create property Station.category LINK Category
create property Category.name STRING

create index Station.category ON Station (category) NOTUNIQUE

insert into category(name) values ("category A") // 13:0
insert into category(name) values ("category B") // 13:1
insert into Station(name,category) values ("Station 1",#13:0)
insert into Station(name,category) values ("Station 2",#13:1)
```

[image]

JAVA

[image]